CNN Training Accuracy Versus Validation Using SGD

The  data is the Canadian Institute for Advanced Research (CIFAR10) image dataset.
The optimizer is SGD
Learning Rate is 0.01
Momentum is 0.9
loss is categorical crossentropy
metrics is accuracy
My question is, is this a good model?


"My question is, is this a good model?"........ Please define what you mean by "a good model"
